# Issue with h2o Package in R using subsetted dataframes leading to near perfect prediction accuracy

Tags: r, h2o

I have been stumped on this problem for a very long time and cannot figure it out. I believe the issue stems from subsets of data.frame objects retaining information of the parent but I also feel it's causing issues when training h2o.deeplearning models on what I think is just my training set (though this may not be true). See below for sample code. I included comments to clarify what I'm doing but it's fairly short code:

```
dataset = read.csv("dataset.csv")[,-1] # Read dataset in but omit the first column (it's just an index from the original data)
y = dataset[,1] # Create response
X = dataset[,-1] # Create regressors

X = model.matrix(y~.,data=dataset) # Automatically create dummy variables
y=as.factor(y) # Ensure y has factor data type
dataset = data.frame(y,X) # Create final data.frame dataset

train = sample(length(y),length(y)/1.66) # Create training indices -- A boolean
test = (-train) # Create testing indices

h2o.init(nthreads=2) # Initiate h2o

# BELOW: Create h2o.deeplearning model with subset of dataset.
mlModel = h2o.deeplearning(y='y',training_frame=as.h2o(dataset[train,,drop=TRUE]),activation="Rectifier",
                           hidden=c(6,6),epochs=10,train_samples_per_iteration = -2)


predictions = h2o.predict(mlModel,newdata=as.h2o(dataset[test,-1])) # Predict using mlModel
predictions = as.data.frame(predictions) # Convert predictions to dataframe object. as.vector() caused issues for me
predictions = predictions[,1] # Extract predictions

mean(predictions!=y[test])
```

The problem is that if I evaluate this against my test subset I get almost 0% error:

```
[1] 0.0007531255
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? Have an idea of how to alleviate this problem?

Comment: I discovered something new. The problem arises when the response is coerced to type factor. Not sure why this is causing issues but if I allow the categorical response to be numerical, I can get relatively reasonable error. This is not ideal though because I cannot use the Cross Entropy loss function and it's not proper statistics.

Comment: This issue arises even if you don't explicitly coerce the response. If you read the dataframe in with levels "Yes" and "No" you get the same problem... I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more efficient to use the H2O functions to load the data and split it.

```
data = h2o.importFile("dataset.csv")
y = 2 #Response is 2nd column, first is an index
x = 3:(ncol(data))  #Learn from all the other columns
data[,y] = as.factor(data[,y])

parts = h2o.splitFrame(data, 0.8)  #Split 80/20
train = parts[[1]]
test = parts[[2]]

# BELOW: Create h2o.deeplearning model with subset of dataset.
mlModel = h2o.deeplearning(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train,activation="Rectifier",
                           hidden=c(6,6),epochs=10,train_samples_per_iteration = -2)

h2o.performance(mlModel, test)
```

It is hard to say what the problem with your original code is, without seeing the contents of dataset.csv and being able to try it. My guess is that train and test are not being split, and it is actually being trained on the test data.

Comment: In addition, the problem could be in the dataset itself. Are you sure the data is actually IID?

Comment: I had had this on my mind for some time now. I had found the h2o.importFile() function and utilized it successfully. You are 100% correct. This was my first time working with something like h2o. Utilizing the h2o functions led to successful splitting and evaluation. Thank you for your response! I hope if someone else has this issue that they find this :) Have a good day sir!

Comment: Regarding IID data, generally speaking I am. By that I mean that I don't have issues of singularity. But I don't expect the entire dataset to be IID. Unless I'm misunderstanding, I don't believe identical distribution of regressors is feasible with large datasets.